# Use DISTINCT properly joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, distinct

```
SELECT * FROM f_posts 
INNER JOIN f_topics 
ON f_posts.post_topic=f_topics.topic_id
INNER JOIN f_subcategories
ON f_subcategories.scat_id=f_topics.topic_scat
ORDER BY f_posts.post_date
DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

I would like to list the first 3 results, and since the last 3 comments were in the same topic, I get the same topic 3 times. Nor DISTINCT nor GROUP BY seems to work.

Comment: can you give sample records where we can test it? and also your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT p.* , t.*, s.*
FROM f_posts p
INNER JOIN (select post_topic, max(post_date) max_date
            from f_posts
            group by post_topic
            order by max_date desc LIMIT 0,3) m
        ON p.post_topic = m.post_topic and p.post_date = m.max_date
INNER JOIN f_topics t ON p.post_topic=t.topic_id
INNER JOIN f_subcategories s ON s.scat_id=t.topic_scat
ORDER BY f_posts.post_date DESC
```